# When to use Protocols like Sequence, Iterator, Collection in Swift

Tags: swift, iterator, protocols, sequence, comparable

I was going thru swift tutorials and I come across examples implementing protocols like Sequence, sometimes Collection, sometimes Iterator

I looked when to really use this protocols but I never found one. All other materials says how to use it but not when to use it.

Can someone please advice where I can learn this. Any quick tip would really be helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Writing routines for specific types, such as `Array`, is often simplest, but writing them for the `Sequence` protocol, for example, offers greater flexibility. I most commonly come across this when writing extensions for collections, which, by definition, can be reused elsewhere and where flexibility is of the greatest value.

Consider, for example, this `Array` extension that sums or prints the values:

```swift
extension Array where Element == Int {
    func sum() -> Int {
        var sum = 0
        for element in self {
            sum += element
        }
        return sum
    }

    func printValues() {
        print("printing values")
        for element in self {
            print(element)
        }
    }
}
```

That obviously works if you really have an array, e.g.

```swift
let array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
let total = array.sum()                 // fine
array.printValues()                     // fine
```

But that won’t work if you have a subrange, for example:

```swift
let total = array[0...3].sum()          // this won’t work
array[0...3].printValues()              // this won’t work
```

Or if you have a set:

```swift
let set: Set = [1, 2, 3]
let total = set.sum()                   // this won’t work
```

You would have to convert this sub array or that `Set` to array to work. However, rather than defining this as an `Array` extension, you can instead define your extension on `Sequence`:

```swift
extension Collection where Element: AdditiveArithmetic {
    func sum() -> Element {
        var sum: Element = .zero
        for element in self {
            sum += element
        }
        return sum
    }
}

extension Sequence where Element: CustomStringConvertible {
    func printValues() {
        print("printing values")
        for element in self {
            print(element)
        }
    }
}
```

It looks pretty much the same, but these rendition will work for the appropriate types, e.g.:

```swift
let array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
print(array[0..<3].sum())               // works for array slices
array[0..<3].printValues()    
(200..<300).printValues()               // or ranges
```

In the above, I used `Sequence`/`Collection` where appropriate. I also changed `sum` so that rather than being limited to integers, it can be used for any type that conforms to `AdditiveArithmetic` (unsigned integers, 32-bit integers, floating point types, etc.). Likewise, for `printValues`, it now supports any sequence that has values that conform to `CustomStringConvertible` (i.e., anything that can be printed). In both cases, the idea is to make the extension as flexible as possible so it works with any type that is logical for the method in question.

```swift
let total = [1.25, 2.3, 3.3].sum()
["moe", "larry", "curly"].printValues()
```

A few more examples where I might favor a protocol over a particular type:

- When writing a routine that takes string input, I might write it to accept `StringProtocol`, so that the routine accepts both strings and substrings, (e.g. `string[start..<end]`).
- I employ a similar thought process when dealing with ranges, where the algorithm ideally should work on a closed range, open range, partial range, etc. I’ll use `RangeExpression` where I need some flexibility, and I’ll just use `Range` when I’m looking for something quick and simple.

That having been said, often writing the method for a particular type is simpler than writing one for the protocol, so one should balance the flexibility afforded by using a protocol over the ease of writing the method for a particular type. Personally, if it’s some private method that won’t be used elsewhere, I’ll go ahead and write the easy, type-specific rendition, but if it’s some public/internal utility method that might enjoy some re-use, I’ll use the protocol renditions for greatest flexibility.

Bottom line, when writing a method, ask yourself whether it’s only important that the method only works for `Array` types, or whether there are other sequences that the same routine might be useful.

---

In terms of when I use `Sequence` or iterators for my own types, that’s a far less common. I’ll do this where I am writing a true “sequence”, where the next value is generated from the preceding value(s), e.g. a Fibonacci sequence or this [count-and-say sequence](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/219222/54422). You can end up with some very natural interactions with the sequence at the calling point rather than shoe-horning the results into an array. But we don’t tend to encounter this pattern nearly as frequently as simple arrays in real-world applications.

Answer (score 0):

There can be many use cases, one like below:

To create CUSTOM count down with steps

```swift
struct MyIterator: IteratorProtocol {
   
    let counter: MyCounter
    var times = 0
    
    mutating func next() -> Int? {
        
        let next = counter.start - times
        
        guard next > 0 else { return nil }
        
        times += counter.steps
        
        return next
    }
}

struct MyCounter: Sequence {
    
    let start: Int
    let steps: Int
    
    func makeIterator() -> MyIterator {
        return MyIterator(counter: self)
    }
}
```

and use it as counter as below

```swift
let myCounter = MyCounter(start: 30, steps: 5)
for count in myCounter {
    print("\(count)...")
}
```

OUTPUT

```swift
30...
25...
20...
15...
10...
5...
```